# Multi-Monitor video playback with controls one screen and video on another

Tags: windows-8, graphics, media, presentations, extended-desktop

I am looking for a free piece of software that will allow me to play a video/DVD on two monitors.

I don't want to span the video. Ideally I would like to have the full-screen video play on my second screen (projector) and have the movie play on my laptop screen with video/show controls etc..

So in other words, I'm looking something similar to Microsoft's PowerPoint presenter view, but for movies.

My laptop's running 64-bit Windows 8, and it has hybrid graphics (NVIDIA GT 540M & Intel HD Graphics 3000).

I have tried searching for solutions online, but I haven't come across anything that meets my need yet.

I hope someone here can point me in the right direction.

And, finally I don't want to use "Cloned" desktop, since the projector & laptop screen run on different resolutions and it's distracting when I'm doing a presentation to change between extended and cloned desktop.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not personally aware of anything that would do this automatically I'm afraid.

One of the issues is that your 2nd monitor often will not have the capabilities of the primary monitor due to the way that graphics cards are built. Many of them only have the required video hardware acceleration (needed to do the required scaling) on the primary output.

Of course, there is nothing stopping you using a tool that has separate windows for control and display and manually moving the windows to where you want them.

I believe that [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) will do this if you reconfigure the interface using the options settings.

Comment: vlc does have a web control option I think